# Angularjs infinate loop without #! in url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS v1.6.5

When I navigate through the pages of the website normally the URL is in the form of:

> https://mySite.co.uk/#!/login

However when I type in an address without the hash-bang the site goes into an infinite loop and the following message is displayed in the browser console output:

> WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

My route provider looks like this

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  }).
  //ALL ELSE
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

I have an interceptor listening for HTTP error messages however this doesn't seem to be being called:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', '$localStorage', function ($q, $location, $localStorage) {
  return {
    'responseError': function (response) {
      if (response.status === 404) {
        window.location = "/";
      }
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found is to use html5 mode to remove the #! from the URL, then the '.otherwise' route in the route provider catches any other requests.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Then in the index.html add:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
</head>
```